# SVG Tooltip Using Groups

Tags: svg, tooltip

It is my first time here, and I'm looking for an answer about SVG. I just want show a tool tip on hover over a group of my svg.

I am preparing this website, and I need to create a few tool tips in different images, but when I try, it doesn't apply the change. I am reading all about the content of this topic but don't have the answer.

Here is the index with the code, external link because it has 44000 characters:
[google drive share](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwTSc14tNfa_bHQ4UmIwM3VPMjQ)

Comment: permission required to open the google drive link

Comment: It would be better to post what you have tried and a small section of the code in question rather than link to a Google drive account as permissions and links can change and we want the community to be able to see everything in the future.

Comment: sorry, here is the new link with the files shared https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwTSc14tNfa_bHQ4UmIwM3VPMjQ&usp=sharing

Comment: create `<title>` child elements and their text contents will display as tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want a tooltip when you hover certain parts of your svg?

In the source code of the svg each element is defined within a `<path></path>`. Find the code for the area you want the tooltip for and before the opening `<path>` include:`<title>tooltip text</title>`.